# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS while accessing core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, iphonecoredatarecipes

I've made a generic function in app delegate to access core data from anywhere in the app.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)createFetchRequestWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate inEntity:(NSString *)str_entity {

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:str_entity];
        request.predicate = predicate;
        [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
        NSMutableArray *arr_records = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:nil]] mutableCopy];
        return arr_records;
}
```

Now most of the times this function works fine. But once in a hundred or so times it results in a crash with following log:

**EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000000432b2b10**

Can anybody sort out where the problem is.

Comment: Why don't you at least use the `error` parameter?

Comment: @vadian I've tried using try catch. But that doesn't work here as this is a memory issue. So I guess there is no sense using error parameter.

Comment: is it on iOS 10 n above ?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari it's on iOS 9 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is due to threading issue. As it is generic function and it can be called from anywhere in the app, use @synchronize(self) { } . Also add NSError parameter to executeFetchRequest method and handle error also.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)createFetchRequestWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate inEntity:(NSString *)str_entity {
   @synchronize(self) {

     NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:str_entity];
     request.predicate = predicate;
     [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
     NSError *error = nil;

     NSMutableArray *arr_records = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]] mutableCopy];

      if (!error) {
       return arr_records;
      } else 
        nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: That `if` is only useful if `managedObjectContext` is nil, but the error message in the question shows that it's not nil. It's probably deallocated, as you say, but it's not nil.

Comment: I agree to your point but the reason I mentioned that way is Rohitax Rajguru had already tried with error but it seems it is not working for him.

Comment: Sure, but that's different. Your code has a check that is not going to be useful in this situation.

Comment: @VinitIngale : It's not working with this condition.

Comment: @TomHarrington: any idea you having?

Comment: I hope it is due to threading issue. As it is generic function and it can be called from anywhere in the app, use @synchronize(self) { } . Also add NSError parameter to executeFetchRequest method and handle error also.

Comment: @VinitIngale can you give me a little example?

Comment: Did "@synchronize(self) { }" help?